Convert a shape interface{} to []byte leads to "values are not fixed-sized" (binary encoder) or "no exported fields" (gob) but I can't change structs
I have a shape interface{} depicting a circle, a square, or something else.
I need to return it as binary in a []byte array.

If I use the binary encoder

import "encoding/binary"
var buffer bytes.Buffer
errCvtBytes := binary.Write(&buffer, binary.BigEndian, shape)

I'm receiving the error message:
_binary.Write: some values are not fixed-sized in type xml.Circle_

If I use the gob encoder:

import "encoding/gob"
var buffer bytes.Buffer
enc := gob.NewEncoder(&buffer)
gob.Register(xml.Circle{})
   /* ... others registrations ... */
errCvtBytes := enc.Encode(shape)

gob: type util.DateTime has no exported fields
In both cases, encoders are surely right!
Given structs may have variable length values for some, no exported fields for others.
But they aren't mine. And I can't change any of these structures, given to me as normatives. They have stay how they are. Exactly.
Knowing this, do I have a way remaining to make Go succeed in converting an object having one of these structures to binary?
a third encoder to try?

Just converting things as a "binary ... []byte array" is simple: func binarizeEverything(any) []byte { return nil }. The problem is doing this in a manner that can be inverted (binarizeEverything fails here). If something has unexported (but important) fields it cannot be unmrshaled again from you byte slice. It thus makes no sense to look for a way to marshal them in the first place. You have to redeisgn.

@Volker don't be so pessimistic. Most programming languages are able to serialize  any object into binary since their day one. Java with ObjectOutputStream and ByteArrayInputStream, for example. So no, the solution isn't returning nil... :-) nil would only say: "Go lacks another functionality, and we have no hope to see it". I hope there's a workaround!

Even Java cannot do that in the general case. Think of a open network connection. You seem to completely misses the substance of my comment. It's not about serialization but about roundtripping i.e. serialisation and deserialisation.

@Volker Do you have any example of a Java class annotated with Serializable that you cannot convert to a binary stream? None. All of them can. Since the origin of Java. You can put in your class any nesting of variable members or reference to members, or interfaces, it will work. Whatever, the problem is not here. When I ask Go to create a []byte stream from a struct, it has to succeeded. If I create a a := MyComplexStruct{...}, a content, how much dispatched in memory is it, can be retrieved (else how would you access to struct member content at runtime) and therefore: converted to binary

Then you should use Java for your problem. Always use the proper tools. And if Java is so much better in serializing everything than Go you probably would benefit from using Java. I just wonder if I remember the "origin of Java" wrong as in my personal history annotations weren't part of Java since the beginning. But I may be wrong.

You really don't have it. What I point you is that Java (or C, C++) and most languages have a serialization mechanism able to transform a struct (or class) to a byte array or stream. Go should have one too. Currently, it is able to serialize in json, but being able to serialize any struct into a []byte (to carry it elsewhere, to another Go instance, in example) , and unserialize it there is a normal expectation. How to Marshall / Unmarshall any struct to []byte?

I do get it. Go's native serialization is e.g. via encoding/gob which does what you want. (You might have to do a little dance with bytes.Buffer as you insist on []byte, but that is just a few trivial lines of code.) But as you noticed this doesn't work if the internals are hidden. This should be logical, and this is as in any other language and I gave a real example in which Java, C and C++ (your example languages) fail too. I understand that you doubt they fail here too, but that is not a fault of mine. Please tune down your tone a bit.

When you want to control the serialization format of business objects you might not control or that might change, it's beneficial to copy the data into your own structures. Copying is usually pretty cheap compared to serialization, you can annotate the structures like you want and version them accordingly, e.g. keep old versions around.
Whatever the best representation for your business logic is might not match the requirements for a defined serialization format.
